# Reporting using .net 4.0 Window application

Tags: .net, reporting

I have developed one window application which requires one report to be print. This would be one page report. Can you please help me to find most appropriate and easy way to do so.

Report does not has any chart or table. it only plain text where some values are coming from database.

Currently i have one option in my mind is to use Word or excel to do so.

Please help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built-in RDLC format.

See [gotreportviewer.com](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) for a "getting started" tutorial.